# Angular lazy loading not working in my project

Tags: angular, angular6, lazy-loading

I tried to convert normal routig with Lazylading and got the following exception:

The full sourse code is available in GIT. (master branch)
https://github.com/bala-itpro-channel/Easy-Accounting.git

> Error: Invalid configuration of route 'master'. One of the following
>   must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren

Can anyone help to identify my mistake please

Comment: Wrong spelling in your app-routing.ts, `loadChilderen` should be `loadChildren`.

Comment: Thanks wannadream. I fixed it and now I got the following error.

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at webpackAsyncContext

Comment: I realized that i had imported my lazy-loaded module into my app-module by mistake. I removed the lazy-loading module from app-module. It's working now :)